# Query formula not displaying results that start with (') leading apostrophe strings

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

[I have a sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17MNG8Q_qJ8JuCyLdMcMc-yWrH0ErdWIxY70y_CONQZs/edit#gid=0) where I need to use query formula

It doesn't display data that start with `'` symbol (strings).

How do I make them display? The red cells are empty.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Query](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) considers only **one** data type for each column. As it is stated in the official documentation:

> In case of mixed data types in a single column, the majority data type
> determines the data type of the column for query purposes. Minority
> data types are considered null values.

---

Therefore, the solution is to change the format to **Plain text** for **column A**.

**Result:**

[image: output]

Answer (score 3):

You mentioned

> I have a sheet here where **I need to use query formula**

You can use the following formula:

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A),TEXT(A2:A,0),"")))
```

[image]

*(Following that, you can leave the cells as text or change them to numbers depending on their further use.)*

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [`LEN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094081)
- [`TEXT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139)

Answer (score 2):

You can also convert column to text inside `QUERY`:

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(TO_TEXT(Sheet1!A2:A),"select *"))
```

[image]

Comment: Much better. :)